# How to understand the output of "adb shell dumpsys activity activities"

Tags: android, adb, dumpsys

I implemented an automated testing tool to test my Android app. I need to frequently check the back stack of activities. So I use the following command to show it:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity activities | sed -En -e '/Stack #/p' -e '/Running activities/,/Run #0/p' | grep -i <package_name>/
```

Most of the times I see outputs like this because activity `a.b` opens activity `c.d`:

```
Run #1: ActivityRecord{8d12c4 u0 <package_name>/.c.d t5}
Run #0: ActivityRecord{1bb16d2 u0 <package_name>/.a.b t5}
```

However, sometimes I see outputs like this:

```
Run #1: ActivityRecord{8d12c4 u0 <package_name>/.a.b t5}
Run #0: ActivityRecord{1bb16d2 u0 <package_name>/.c.d t5 f}
```

The second line ends with an `f}`. What is the meaning of it? Does `f` stand for "finished"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer. See the `toString` method in this [class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.0.2_r1/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityRecord.java#1234)

It means finishing